# How to debug unexplained battery usage?

Tags: battery, sleep-wake, power

I have an M1 Air (Sonoma 14.1.2), which most of the time has a reasonable battery life. However, sometimes it inexplicably drains battery, as shown on the second Friday here where ~27% of the battery is consumed without me ever touching the machine:

[image: power usage over time]

Most days, power usage seems proportional to screen-on time (i.e. I am actually using the machine). The battery item in the menu bar claimed no apps were using significant energy.

Here's a similar effect that just happened overnight. I used the Air yesterday evening, but then through the night ~25% was steadily lost.

[image: overnight battery drain]

Looking at the output of `pmset -g log`, I see there is an almost continuous stream of events being logged, such as this recurring burst of 3 events, repeating every 15 minutes:

```
2024-01-09 01:31:48 +0000 Assertions PID 22686(com.apple.PassKit.PaymentAuthor) Summary PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "Cancelling Apple Pay transaction" 298:59:49 id:0x0x10000a678 [System: PrevIdle]
2024-01-09 01:31:48 +0000 Assertions PID 22686(com.apple.PassKit.PaymentAuthor) Summary PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "Cancelling Apple Pay transaction" 363:01:24 id:0x0x100009399 [System: PrevIdle]
2024-01-09 01:31:48 +0000 Assertions PID 22686(com.apple.PassKit.PaymentAuthor) Summary PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "Cancelling Apple Pay transaction" 367:45:53 id:0x0x10000916e [System: PrevIdle]
```

(always the same PID, going back as far as `pmset -g log` can see - Jan 2nd)

Strangely, after a week, now that particular process is no longer running. That 15 minute interval is probably frequent enough interruptions that the machine was never truly sleeping.

I deliberately leave very little running. For example, I always close Music, Xcode and the simulator, even if it feels like that shouldn't be a requirement.
(unless it's been fixed, those dynamic album covers seem to drain power even when Music isn't visible)

Is there a way to get more fine-grained (and preferably historical) energy usage info than is offered by the menu bar?

## Update (5 days later)

Focussing on that unexpected and repeating "Cancelling Apple Pay transaction" log message, which crucially is setting`PreventUserIdleSystemSleep`, it seems likely that is the culprit.

Coincidentally, I used Apple Pay on it again a couple of days ago, and again the drain-without-use happened, and again `com.apple.PassKit.PaymentAuthor` was "spamming" the logs every 15 minutes. I `kill -9`'d the process yesterday (regular `kill` had no effect) and since then there has been close to zero battery drain. I've reported it via https://feedbackassistant.apple.com

This machine gets irregular and light usage. It is rarely rebooted. Maybe the phenomenon is "lost in the noise" for machines that are more heavily used.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you do your proposed solution `pmset -g log` worked for my issue too, except that the pid was `37008` for the same process. So far killing the process has worked. Reported the same issue to Apple, hoping they'll work it out.